# removing character using substr in perl

Tags: perl, substr

I'm trying to remove two character from the string

```
This is what you have
```

using

```
substr ($string, 5, 2) = "";
```

The two characters are getting removed, but one extra space is left behind. I obtain

```
This  what you have
```

but I desire to get

```
This what you have
```

Can anyone help me to get rid of that space?

Comment: What's the original input?  If you're trying to remove "is" from "This is what you have" you just have to remove 3 characters instead of 2.

Comment: Thank You Jim Davis your suggestion works..

Comment: @JimDavis: Please post your comment as a solution, so that the OP can accept it and mark the question as being answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string, like an array, starts at position 0:

```
say '012345679';
my $str = "This is what you have";
say $str;

--output:--
012345679
This is what you have
```

To remove 'is' and the space preceding 'is', you need to remove positions 4, 5, 6:

```
012345679
This is what you have
    ^^^
    |||
```

...which you can do like this:

```
say '012345679';
my $str = "This is what you have";
say $str;

substr($str, 4, 3) = "";
say $str;

--output:--
012345679
This is what you have
This what you have
```

Alternatively, you can remove 'is' and the space after 'is' by removing positions 5, 6, 7:

```
012345679
This is what you have
     ^^^
     |||
```

...like this:

```
say '012345679';
my $str = "This is what you have";
say $str;

substr($str, 5, 3) = "";
say $str;

--output:--
012345679
This is what you have
This what you have
```

However, in perl most people use `s///` (the substitution operator) for making substitutions:

```
s/find me/replace with me/
```

So, you can do this:

```
my $str = "This is what you have"; 
say $str;

$str =~ s/\bis\b //;  # \b means 'word boundary'
say $str;

--output:--
012345679
This is what you have
This what you have
```

perl programmers are lazy, and counting positions is too hard.  You *do* need to know regexes for most situations.

If you want to remove all occurrences of 'is ' in a string, then you can add the 'g' (global) flag:

```
my $str = "This is what you have, but his hat is black isn't it?";
say $str;

$str =~ s/\bis\b //g;
say $str;

--output:--
This is what you have, but his hat is black isn't it?
This what you have, but his hat black isn't it?
  ^                      ^            ^
  |                      |            |
    skips 'is' embedded in other words
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to remove the word `is` and one of the spaces next to it from `This is what you have`, you'll need to remove 3 characters instead of just 2.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can assign a string to the result of the substr command, like you are trying to do, and get the expected result.  Try it this way instead:

$newstring=substr($string,0,4) . substr($string,5);

Comment: `substr` can act as an lvalue, it's fine.